# Google Backup and Sync - potential disaster? How does it operate?

Tags: backup, sync, google-drive, online-backup

Does anyone actually know how GB&S actually works?

Not for the first time, I have had to put a block on the use of this tool. Because I have witnessed it deleting a file on my main machine which it shouldn't have deleted, and which is a vitally important file.  Fortunately I have redundant backup arrangements, and have been getting quite suspicious of GB&S recently, so taking things defensively.

I believe the reason it deleted it is because I am attempting to keep two machines in sync with one another through their use of GB&S using a shared Google Drive. Although I have found nothing definitive out there which says you shouldn't do that, I'm pretty much convinced now that that is a sure route to disaster and intend to stop forthwith.

And it isn't helped by the fact that I can find absolutely no information whatsoever about how GB&S determines which end (i.e. Cloud-based Drive space, or local machine) is definitive, in terms of whether a file should be deleted or kept.

So the problem seems to be that machine A had this file, now deleted.  But then I connected machine B, which I hadn't used for about a week or so. The idea was that machine B would "sync up" to what it found in the Cloud (Drive) space.  But what it appears to have done in some cases (as you can see, I am floundering to find out what rules it might be following) is to have decided that the ***Cloud (Drive) space*** was out of date, not its own space. So it deleted some stuff, including that vital file, in the Cloud (Drive) space.

When machine A then booted up again GB&S started operating again, found that file to be missing in the Cloud (Drive) space, and consequently decided it had to be deleted from the local machine (machine A)! File gone!

You might expect that dates, such as the Last modified date of a file/directory, might be involved. But I haven't been able to find any proof of that either way.

Even using GB&S with just a single machine, you have the option, if you so choose, of deleting a file directly in the Cloud (Drive) space, in which case you would then expect, next time GB&S was operating, that file to be deleted in your local machine. But, at the moment of discovering that discrepancy, how does GB&S know which way to sync? (i.e. delete from machine, or upload the file to the Cloud (Drive) space).

Any info/pointers/links greatly appreciated.

Comment: GB&S should not be deleting any files from the cloud that you have not specifically deleted from a machine that was fully synchronized.  A file that exists in the cloud, but not on a machine, should not be deleted.

Comment: Any links to where you get your definitive rules of behaviour from? Plus, when I connected machine B (see above), GB&S found that some files were not present on the local machine, but were present in the Cloud.  How can GB&S "know" whether or not these files have been "specifically deleted" from machine B?

Comment: That link does not exists.  The client knows if it's fully synchronized.  If you add a file, to the folder you are going to synchronized, then it will upload the file.  Likewise, if you delete the file, then the client is going to see that the file no longer exists.  The client knows the files are missing from machine B, and that the files were never synchronized to machine B, if the client is removing the files from the cloud due to the files not being present on machine B that isn't intended behavior.

Comment: You are dealing with a web service, so how the client and the web service communicate the files changes, is behavior that likely is NOT documented by Google.  What I do know is that when a file is deleted on a local machine, the client synchronizes that change with the service, and file in the cloud is marked as being deleted.  This is evident by nothing but by what happens in the cloud

Comment: Clearly GB&S somehow "tags" files and directories: you can see this with the green tick (or red cross) icon which you see next to files/directories in Windows Explorer, for example.  On the face of it, though, it does appear, from my experience, that (sometimes) an absent/deleted file on the local machine (which will be seen as "not fully synchronised") can result in deletion in the Cloud. I'm willing to believe this is solely due to my attempt to sync two machines. Would you say you have never experienced any problems of this kind? You sound like an experienced user of it.

Comment: Honestly, I synchronize my Google Drive folder between multiple cloud providers, I sacrifice having duplicates on my local drive to have multiple individual copies in the cloud.  I also very rarely delete anything in the cloud.

Comment: I use GB&S across numerous computers, even replicating data with sub folders that are shared out on other computers using different users. I don’t have any issues other than the tool stops responding to right-clicks sometimes and it sometimes stops syncing all together requiring a restart. I’ve never had an issue like you describe. Google also provides file history and a trash so there shouldn’t be any reason you can’t easily recover whatever is misplaced. If you are creating collisions by accessing the same file on different computers at the same time while offline there will be problems.

Comment: @Appleoddity +1 for reminding me that everything is just deleted to the Recycle Bin: I've now restored several thousand files GB&S deleted earlier this evening, and some vital stuff which had stopped functioning has now recovered. Where is the "file history" you speak of?  Yes, I must have been unwittingly been making probs for myself. Must find a proper tool for maintaining sync between machines.